# What are the limitations/drawbacks of using single azure app service to host multiple applications/microservices?

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Can anyone tell me or explain me what are the limitations/drawbacks of deploying multiple micro services (say 2-3)  on a single Azure AppService server?

To achieve following we use microservies

- Serve a single purpose or have a single responsibility
- Have a clear interface for communication
- Have less dependencies on each other
- Can be deployed independently without affecting the rest of ecosystem
- Can scale independently
- Can fail independently
- Allow your teams to work independently, without relying on other teams for support and services
- Allow small and frequent changes
- Have less technical debts
- Have a faster recovery from failure

But How the Azure app service works when we try to deploy one of the microservice? will it impact other mircoservices? can we use this it in production environments?

I came across few links hosting mutiple apps on single appservice by defining virtual path for windows and for linux by adding azure storage but is it best/good practice to do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to hosting multiple App Service apps in a shared App Service plan. This is conceptually (and physically) the same as running multiple apps on a server, and I would think about pros/cons along those lines.

You can host many apps on the same plan as long as the plan provides enough memory/CPU/network resources to cover the needs of the combined demands of those apps. For a few small apps, a modest plan size shouldn't have a problem handling all of them in production. The main benefit of combination is saving costs, since the plan is the unit of charge, not the apps.

Microsoft [documents some reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans) to isolate apps on separate plans:

> - The app is resource-intensive.
> - You want to scale the app    independently from the other apps in the existing plan.
> - The app needs    resource in a different geographical region.

From my experience, I'd add some considerations:

- Deployment and restarting of apps can cause CPU spikes for the plan (which is a server). If your apps are performance sensitive and you deploy often, you might want more separation
- Azure maintenance requires servers to restart at least once a month or more. If all your apps are on a shared plan, a patch reboot can mean the entire system is down and that all apps compete for resources when starting up simultaneously
- I generally use separate plans as environment boundaries, so a production plan separate from a test plan. "Test" apps go on test plan, "Prod" apps on production to prevent testing from impacting users.
- [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) may be better fit for hosting many microservices

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. They will compete for compute resources, and in case of hardware failure all of them will go down.